# I can write iCloud Documents, but cannot see them

Tags: swift, icloud, uidocument

A am working with UIDocuments and iCloud.  I am successfully able to write out a file to iCloud but not seeing in on the device and the files app.

I have the following in info.plist.

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
<dict>
    <key>iCloud.myAppName</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
        <string>myAppName</string>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
        <string>Any</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Inside my code I can create the directory and then write the file.

```
   var containerUrl: URL? {
                    return FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("myAppName")
                }          
  let url =  containerUrl?.appendingPathComponent("fileName.fileType")           

     print("url: \(url)")
```

The print returns:

file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~myAppName/myAppName/fileName.fileType

I can test and see that the files are written out with code such as:

```
let boolTest: Bool = !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: testUrl!.path, isDirectory: nil)
print("!file exist: \(boolTest)")
```

In the "Signing & Capabilities" tab of my Target under iCloud I have clicked "iCloud Documents" and have a container called iCloud.myAppName that is assigned to my Team.  (Note:  There are two other checks "Key-value storage" and "CloudKit".  I have tried those both ways.  I believe they should be unchecked.)

Regardless, all seems to work well.  I can see through the fileExist that it is written.  However, I cannot see the documents in the File app or pull up the documents through the app.  Only the documents on the device.

At this point, I am not sure what I am missing.  Nor do I have any ideas as to how to debug this.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem? What as the solution?

Comment: Never solved it.   One of the many problems that led me to realize I was not going to accomplish what I wanted to do (and perhaps why there are few apps that do this).  I moved on to other things.

Answer (score 0):

Save them within the `Documents` folder in cloud container. No need to add `.appendingPathComponent("myAppName")`